# how to configure oracle listener when server & client are on same box

Tags: oracle, configuration, listener

I have 2 Oracle database servers. How can I configure the listener(s) and TNS names on the local server so that the local server can run external procedures and access the remote one?

So far I have the following non-working configurations. What is wrong with it? Many thanks.

```
****TNSNAMES.ORA****
local_instance =
  (description =
    (address_list =
      (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = localhost)(port = 1521))
      (address = (protocol = ipc)(key=extproc0))      
    )
    (connect_data =
      (service_name = local_instance)
    )
  )

remote_instance =
  (description =
    (address_list =
      (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(port = 1521))
    )
    (connect_data =
      (service_name = remote_instance)
    )
  )

****LISTENER.ORA****  
listener =
  (description =
    (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = localhost)(port = 1526))
  )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what works for us:

```
# TNSNAMES.ORA

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

local_instance =
  (description =
    (address_list =
      (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = localhost)(port = 1521))
    )
    (connect_data =
      (service_name = local_instance)
    )
  )

remote_instance =
  (description =
    (address_list =
      (address = (protocol = tcp)(host = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)(port = 1521))
    )
    (connect_data =
      (service_name = remote_instance)
    )
  )

# LISTENER.ORA
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\oracle\10.2.0_DB)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS="EXTPROC_DLLS=ANY")
    )
  )
LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC0))
    )
  )
```